# GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP vs. GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE

Tags: opengl, mipmaps

If we generate mipmaps for a texture using `GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP` (or `glGenerateMipmap`), how big can the original texture be? Is it the size returned by `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE`, or half of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be neither. The value of `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` is not to be trusted, as the specification calls it a "rough estimate of the largest texture that the GL can handle". It might be much smaller, it might even be larger, depending on the `format`, `internalformat`  and `type` parameters of `glTexImage2D`.

The correct way to determine whether or not a texture is too large, is to use texture proxies. Then just trust `glGenerateMipmap()` will succeed. (The documented failure modes for `glGenerateMipmap()` don't say anything about a maximum size.)

If you want to be really sure, you could check the sizes of each mipmap level using `glGetTexLevelParameteriv()` to see if all went well.